# Unable to generate a URL for the named route "clone"

Tags: symfony, routes, sonata

I am following the instructions at https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html to build a custom CRUDController in a Symfony/Sonata application.

When I look at the list view, I get the following error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "clone" as such route
>   does not exist.").

Is there additional code needed in order to get the application to recognize my new route?

Answer (score 0):

Ah -- I had to put my configureRoutes() definition in the admin class rather than the controller class. The documentation was wrong.